# Get id of clicked Object within Group

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[   
private function handleClick(id:String):void {
            trace("id clicked: " + id);
            if(id == "1") {
                trace("1 clicked");
            } else if(id=="2") {
                trace("2 clicked");
            } else {
                trace("Nothing");
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" click="handleClick()" >
        <s:BitmapImage id="1"/>
        <s:BitmapImage id="2"/>
</s:Group>
```

Hello. Based on the code above, I am trying to pass the id of the clicked BitmapImage to the handleClick function. What is the best way for me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to handle the click of the BitmapImage, you will need to put it inside a Group or other container that can handle it, the example below will work for you:

```
<![CDATA[   
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private function handleClick(event:Event):void {
                var id:String = event.target.id;
                trace("id clicked: " + id);
                if(id == "1") {
                    trace("1 clicked");
                } else if(id=="2") {
                    trace("2 clicked");
                } else {
                    trace("Nothing");
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" click="handleClick(event)" >
        <s:Group id="b1" >
            <s:BitmapImage />
        </s:Group>
        <s:Group id="b2" >
            <s:BitmapImage />
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
```

Comment: This one worked well, but it's messy to declare nested Groups, in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: I agree... Adobe suggests to use one Graphic instead a Group, take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
click="handleClick(event)"

...handleClick(event:Event)
{
   trace(event.target.id); // this is what you want
}
```